# React: input type "file" ignores `accept` property when you upload files using drag and drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, input-type-file

I use `<input type="file" accept=".txt" />` with accept property. I set it to accept, for example, only `.txt` files. And it works well if you click on `input` and opens the chooser and you cannot upload files that not allowed by `accept`.

But, when you upload files by `drag & drop` it uploads any files ignoring `accept`.

Here is an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-tdd-11wt9?file=/src/App.js

To reproduce the problem:

- drag any file from you Desktop, expect `.txt`
- move and drop into the input
- you'll see a file name (but it should not be uploaded)

Q: What is the best way to work this around? Considering there could any fileTypes and standard `file.type` gives excessive information about file type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the accept, the browser tells the OS to show only the files which are mentioned but the support, but when you do a drag and drop this feature is eliminated ,
The best way is to write a validator function that checks whether the given file is supported or not like

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
const newFiles = e.target.files;
const fileName = newFiles[0].name;
const extension = fileName.split(".").pop();
const isSupported = ["txt"].includes(extension);
if (!isSupported) {
  alert("not supported");
  setFiles(null);
  e.target.value = null;
} else {
  setFiles(newFiles);
}
```

};

here the advantage of using `["txt"].includes(extension)` is that , you can add validation for multiple file types, I just reset the input with  `e.target.value = null;`(when the file is invalid) , but you can use you own logic there

here is a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-glade-gqyyv?file=/src/App.js:129-493)

Answer (score 2):

To prevent drop unaccepted files you need to add `onDrop` handler for input:

```
<input type="file" onDrop={handleDrop} accept="text/plain" {...otherProps} />
```

In `onDrop` check if dropped file type is accepted:

```
const handleDrop = (e) => {
  const allowedTypes = new Set([e.target.accept]);
  if (!allowedTypes.has(e.dataTransfer.files[0].type)) {
    // stop event prepagation
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

Here is a live example:

[image: Edit kind-jennings-t8947]